# this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority not called ionic 5

Tags: ionic-framework, back-button, back, ionic5

`subscribeWithPriority` is not called using Ionic 5.

This is my `app.component.ts` function:

```
initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      alert("initialed!"); // this called, and I can see this.
      this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, (processNexthandler) => {
        console.log('Back press handler!');
        alert(888) // this never called
      });
   }
}
```

The first alert shows that it calls `initializeApp`, but I never see next the alert `888`. I tried other priorities, like `9999` or `0,` -1`, none of those are working.

How do I call call my function properly using `subscribeWithPriority`?

Answer (score -1):

You have to make sure ion-router-outlet is wrapped by ion-app